Imprimir array multidimencional
Tengo el siguiente array multidimencional. En el caso del proveedor F, G y K, no tienen los 3 elementos que se necesitan para rellenar la matriz:
$grupo = [
        'Cuentas por cobrar' => [
                'Proveedor A' => [
                        'empresa X' => [ 0 => 2 ],    
                        'empresa Y' => [ 0 => 15 ],        
                        'empresa Z' => [ 0 => 51]
                ],        
                'Proveedor F' =>
                    [
                        'empresa X' => [ 0 => 5 ],        
                        'empresa Z' => [ 0 => 63 ]
                    ]
            ],   

        'Cuentas por pagar' => [
                'Proveedor A' =>
                    [
                        'empresa X' => [ 0 => 2 ],        
                        'empresa Y' => [ 0 => 36 ],        
                        'empresa Z' => [ 0 => 74 ]
                    ],        
                'Proveedor F' =>
                    [
                        'empresa X' => [ 0 => 7 ],        
                        'empresa Y' => [ 0 => 47 ],        
                        'empresa Z' => [ 0 => 83 ]
                    ]
            ],    

        'Ventas' => [
                'Proveedor G' =>
                    [
                        'empresa X' => [ 0 => 9 ]
                    ]
            ],      

        'Costos' =>[
                'Proveedor K' =>
                    [
                        'empresa Z' => [ 0 => 566 ]
                    ]
            ]
];

El reporte que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

*Notar que las empresas que no tienen cantidad en la matriz se deben rellenar con cero.
Intente lo siguiente:
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Cuenta</th>
        <th>Proveedor</th>
        <th>Empresa x</th>
        <th>Empresa y</th>
        <th>Empresa z</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($grupo as $indice => $valor) :  // Cuenta ?>
      
        <?php foreach ($valor as $indice2 => $valor2) : // Proveedor ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $indice; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $indice2; ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($valor2 as $empresa => $valor3) : // Empresa y valor

                            foreach ($valor3 as $indice4 => $importe) : // Indice que siempre sera 0 y Monto 
                               
                                echo  '<td>' . $importe . '</td>';

                             
                            endforeach;
                    endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

Obtengo el siguiente reporte, que no es el que deseo, ya que las cantidades las ubica al inicio de la tabla sin importar a que coordenada corresponda:

Ayuda!

dejo un codigo con una opción a la solución
<?php
$grupo = [
    "Cuentas por cobrar" => [
        "Proveedor A" => [
            "empresa X" => [0 => 2],
            "empresa Y" => [0 => 15],
            "empresa Z" => [0 => 51],
        ],
        "Proveedor F" => [
            "empresa X" => [0 => 5],
            "empresa Z" => [0 => 63],
        ],
    ],

    "Cuentas por pagar" => [
        "Proveedor A" => [
            "empresa X" => [0 => 2],
            "empresa Y" => [0 => 36],
            "empresa Z" => [0 => 74],
        ],
        "Proveedor F" => [
            "empresa X" => [0 => 7],
            "empresa Y" => [0 => 47],
            "empresa Z" => [0 => 83],
        ],
    ],

    "Ventas" => [
        "Proveedor G" => [
            "empresa X" => [0 => 9],
        ],
    ],

    "Costos" => [
        "Proveedor K" => [
            "empresa Z" => [0 => 566],
        ],
    ],
];
//ARRAY EMPRESAS
//el siguiente codigo crea un array basado en todas las empresas que se encuentran
$array_empresas = [];
foreach ($grupo as $nombre_grupo => $proveedor) {
    foreach ($proveedor as $nombre_proveedor => $empresa) {
        foreach ($empresa as $nombre_empresa => $valor) {
            if (!in_array($nombre_empresa, $array_empresas)) {
                $array_empresas [] = $nombre_empresa;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Cuenta</th>
        <th>Proveedor</th>
        <?php
            foreach ($array_empresas as $emp) {
                echo "<th>$emp</th>";
            } 
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach ($grupo as $nombre_grupo => $proveedor) {
            foreach ($proveedor as $nombre_proveedor => $empresa) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$nombre_grupo</td>";
                echo "<td>$nombre_proveedor</td>";
                    foreach ($array_empresas as $emp) {
                        //VALOR POR DEFECTO 0
                        $num = 0;
                        foreach ($empresa as $nombre_empresa => $valor) {
                            if($nombre_empresa == $emp){
                                $num = $valor[0];
                            }
                        }
                        echo "<td>$num</td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</table>

Resultado:


Si siempre son 3 empresas, empresa x, empresa y y empresa z, entonces puedes iterar sobre las 3, y si hace falta alguna la rellenas con 0.
Reemplaza la siguiente línea, y todo lo que está dentro, incluyendo el for más interno:
<?php foreach ($valor2 as $empresa => $valor3) :
    ...
endforeach; ?>

Por esto:
<?php foreach (['empresa X', 'empresa Y', 'empresa Z'] as $empresa) :
    $importe = $valor2[$empresa] ?? [0];
    echo  '<td>' . $importe[0] . '</td>';
endforeach; ?>


Muchas gracias, si me sirvió.
